# What are the trademark guidelines for Java technologies?

Tags: java, licensing, trademark

The former page "Trademark and Logo Usage Requirements" at http://www.sun.com/policies/trademarks/ is no longer available, is there a new version which helps with the proper naming of products (beans, libraries) for Java?

I have found Third Party Usage Guidelines for Oracle Trademarks at http://www.oracle.com/us/legal/third-party-trademarks/index.html however there is no occurence of "Java" related product names.

Former guidelines said that "(productname...) for the Java platform" was a correct name, and now it seems to me that it must be renamed to "**(productname...) for Oracle Java**" to comply with the Third Party Usage Guidelines for Oracle Trademarks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask a lawyer.

I'd follow the instructions Oracle give on that page:

> **Credit Line**
>   All products, packaging, manuals, 
>   advertisements, promotional materials
>    and Web pages bearing Oracle
>    trademarks should include the 
>   following trademark credit line.
>   "Oracle and Java are registered
>   trademarks of Oracle and/or its
>   affiliates. Other names may be
>   trademarks of their respective owners."
>   The credit line may appear anywhere
>   on the collateral, but typically is
>   displayed on a copyright page, the back
>   of a package or at the end of a
>   document or web page.

Alternatively contact Oracle directly:

> If you have any questions regarding
>   Oracle trademarks, please contact the
>   Oracle Legal Department at
>   +1.650.506.5200 or trademar_us@
>   oracle.com. back to top Oracle 1-800-633-0738 Have Oracle call you

Answer (score 1):

You do not need permission to use someone else's trademark when describing your own work or comparing your work to theirs.  It is a courtesy to include a trademark notice.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_use

Just because you are abiding by the law doesn't mean they won't sue you.